# Partial least squares regression component selection based on Q2

Tags: regression, cross-validation, dimensionality-reduction, partial-least-squares

I am working on high dimensional biological data and I am trying to use PLSR to build a model and identify important variables. The dataset has 427 X variables and 1 response variable for 16 observations. I am using R package `pls` to obtain these results (function `plsr()`).

This is what the summary of my regression with cross-validation looks like:

[image]

As I understand it, the number of components I should be choosing for my model can be fixed by looking at Q2 and stopping when adding a component increases Q2 by less than 0.05. However, in my particular case, Q2 is very small/negative for the first two components, but it is then much higher for components 3-5.

[image]

I have also tried to look at the plots for calibration and prediction RMSE and I would pick 3 or 5 components.

[image]

Given the very low Q2 in the first 2 components and the high % of Y explained just with the first 2 components, should I just assume that my model is not predictive at all and it is just overfitting the data when I consider more variables? Or can I consider later components as important?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: what coding did you use to get get the Q2 and the RSS values?